# How can I filter the column type of the table using two buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to filter the type column, one button filters the aquatic and in the other all except the aquatic

```html
<button type="button" onclick="Aquatic()">Aquatic</button>    
<button type="button" onclick="NotAquatic()" >everything but aquatic</button>
<table class="table" >      
  <thead>
    <tr>                    
      <th scope="col">Animal</th>
      <th scope="col">Type </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="" >
    <tr>
      <td>bat</td>
      <td>aerial</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fish</td>
      <td>Aquatic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Horse</td>
      <td>Land</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shark</td>
      <td>Aquatic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Elephant</td>
      <td>Land</td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
      <td>Whale</td>
      <td>Aquatic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>dove</td>
      <td>aerial</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps point you in the right direction! have a filterTable function which grabs all the table rows, and removes any inline style changes previously added to display. Then, I filter all the `tr`s by the innerHTML content not including the term, and I take all those `tr`s and set their display to none

```js
function filterTable(aquaShown) {
  const trs = [...document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr")];
  trs.forEach(tr => tr.style.display = "");
  const hiddenTrs = aquaShown ? 
    trs.filter(tr => !tr.innerHTML.includes("Aquatic")) :
    trs.filter(tr => tr.innerHTML.includes("Aquatic"));
  hiddenTrs.forEach(tr => tr.style.display = "none");
}

function aquatic() {
  filterTable(true);
}

function nonaquatic() {
  filterTable(false);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="aquatic()">Aquatic</button>
<button type="button" onclick="nonaquatic()">Non-Aquatic</button>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Animal</th>
            <th scope="col">Type </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="">
        <tr>
            <td>Fish</td>
            <td>Aquatic</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Horse</td>
            <td>Land</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shark</td>
            <td>Aquatic</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Elephant</td>
            <td>Land</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Whale</td>
            <td>Aquatic</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT** refactored based on further clarification in comments

Comment: Thanks, how would you make the other button filter all except the aquatic ones?

Comment: So you want a button that can only hide the rows with `Aquatic` in it?

Comment: The line of code `const hiddenTrs = trs.filter(tr => !tr.innerHTML.includes(term));` grabs the trs to hide. Instead of saying `!tr.innerHTML.includes(term)` you could say something like `tr.innerHTML.includes("Aquatic")` and it would grab all the ones that say aquatic to hide

Comment: A button that shows only the aquatic and another that shows all except the aquatic

Comment: Does that edit help?

Comment: I am working with html through javascript code and I figure that the function is not defined